# How to add a won or loss variable

Tags: python, variables

Hey I'm trying to add a variable for "won" or "loss", I already have a variable for players name and guesses allowed.
Any help would be kind thanks. This is the code I have so far:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
player_name = input("Hello, What's your name?: ")                        
number_of_guesses = 0             

print("Okay! "+ player_name+ " I am guessing a number between 1 and 100:")

max_guesses = random.randint(1, 6)

print("You have " + str(max_guesses) + " guesses. ")

while number_of_guesses < max_guesses:

    guess = int(input())

    number_of_guesses += 1

    if guess < number:


        print("Your guess is too low")

    if guess > number:

        print("Your guess is too high")

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:

    print("You guessed the number in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries!")

else:

    print("You did not guess the number, the number was " + str(number))


f = open("statistics.txt", "a")

f.write =(player_name) (max_guesses)

f.close()

f = open("statistics.txt", "r")

print(f.read())
```

Comment: When you say a variable for won/loss, you mean to save it in file ?

Comment: Have you learned about Boolean values?

Comment: Ah yes that would be the case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add befor you loop the variable `won = False`
And in the loop

```
     if guess == number:
         won = True
         break
```

After the loop if the player don't find the nulber won will be false.
In the oter case it will be True

For saving

```
f.write( str(won) ) # convert to string
```